# Android-TV speech recognition with manual input

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, android-tv

I've implementing voice-search on my Android-TV app using the following small code

```
private void displaySpeechRecognizer() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == -1) {
        List<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String spokenText = results.get(0);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), spokenText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

This is all working well and I get the result back for further processing.

The problem is that I also want to give the user the possibility to enter the search-string manually with the virtual keyboard. 
In Googles own apps you do this be simply pressing RIGHT on the remote to give focus to the textbox after pressing the voice-search icon.

In my example above I can see the "built-in-textbox" when I press the search icon but if I try to navigate to it the search is interrupted and closed.

How do I access the search-textbox? This should cancel voice-input and bring up the keyboard instead, just like Play Store app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Leanback support library for your Android TV app design? 
I guess "Google Play Store app" and "YouTube app" are using BrowseFragment & SearchFragment for search. These Fragments are providing build-in search UI.

For the implementation, see [Google's sample source code](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback) or [SearchFragment – Android TV app Tutorial 12](http://corochann.com/android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-12-287.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links, those got it working, at least some some extent. First search is working fine but on the second try (without leaving the searchfragment) then onQueryTextSubmit does not seem to fire, I'm still left with the results from the first search.

Comment: Your SearchFragment implements SearchResultProvider interface?
At first, you can check onQueryTextChange & onQueryTextSubmit callback is working or not by inserting Logcat log.

Comment: Yes it implements SearchResultProvider. After some debugging I found that onQueryTextSubmit is only called on the first time you press the search button on the virtual keyboard. Searching again from within the same searchfragment only triggers onQueryTextChange. Same result in Googles own example code so this might be by design. I ended up implementing onQueryTextChange with a delay to get around it.

Comment: When I tested Google's example, onQueryTextSubmit worked correctly, when I press "search" of software keyboard button. The tested device is software version 5.1.1 (API level 22).